# Segment and Ad Blockers

Tags: analytics, segment, adblock

I am not able to track user activity via segment when users are having ad blockers enabled?
do we have work around for this? so that we will be able to track user even though ad blocking enabled in browser.

tracking user activity through segment analytics.js when ad blocking enabled in browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use self hosting or proxying Analytics.js on your domain to prevent ad blockers.

See more: https://segment.com/docs/connections/sources/catalog/libraries/website/javascript/custom-proxy/